# ThinkTecture IdentityServer V3 access options at runtime

Tags: c#, thinktecture-ident-server

is it possible to access the thinktecture options at runtime in a controller?

or to be more specific: can i change/swap the signing certificate at runtime?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try looking at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin, there are some API controllers for admin functions which may do what you want. You'd still need to build a UI if you want one.

Comment: Unfortunately the project doesn't help